# Save file in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, mongodb, soap

I am with a problem with MongoDB, I have a Java SOAP web Service and my front is in Angular/Bootstrap/Jquery and I need save a file in my mongo database, but I have no idea how I do this, and I am trying this for 3 days, I need of an example with Jquery/js calling a SOAP service for do this or directly with js, I am receiving the file with `<input type="file" id="file"/>`.
Thank you for your help.
The type of my file is a tgz with a json and a image than I need save in my mongo database.

```
function uploadCard() {
    var fileList = new Array();
    fileList = document.getElementById("file").files;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    if (FileReader && fileList && fileList.length) {
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(fileList[0]);
        imageData = fr.result;
    }

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var wsUrl = "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":7004/CardServiceImpl/CardService?WSDL";
    var soapRequest = crateCardSoapRequest(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: wsUrl,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapRequest,
        success: processSuccess,
        error: processError
    });
    }

    function crateCardSoapRequest(input) {

    var req = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=" + '"' + "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" + '"' + ">" +
            "<soap:Body>" +
            "<ns1:uploadCard xmlns:ns1=" + '"' + " http://card.ejb.card_editor.com.br/" + '"' + ">" +
            "<arg0>" +
            "<cardBean>"+
    "<description>StringValue</description>" +
            "<id>23</id>" +
            "<name>StringValue</name>" +
             "<file>" + input + "</file>" +
            "<template>" + "</template>" +
            "</cardBean>" +
            "<nickNameUser>lucas_santos</nickNameUser>" +
            "</arg0>" +
            "</ns1:uploadCard>" +
            "</soap:Body>" +
            "</soap:Envelope>";

    }
```

My soap parameter is of the type java.io.File

Comment: You say you've been trying for three days. What approaches have you tried during that time, and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: So are you using Angular or jQuery? Anyway, databases don't store files. They store URLs to the files.

Comment: I try pass the file in the soap parameters and the ajax request wasn't recognize my method, I think than I need to convert to binary array or string but I did not has succes in do this.

Comment: In mongo I have how use  BSON or  GridFS (for large files), and just save the file in the database

Comment: I call other web service methods with string and nuber parameters and its ok, the problem is when I use files in my ajax request of Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Databases are meant to store data. You're probably not supposed to stick files (like images, etc.) straight into the database. Instead, upload the file to some storage server or a CDN and link to that from your database.

Then, you query the database, find the URL, and then fetch the resource from that URL.

Comment: Ok, this is other way to do this, but the proposal of my project is storage the file in the database, the mongoDb supports this.

Comment: How I do this, do you have a storage server for images for indicate for me?